# Как через командную строку Windows заменить подстроку в файле?

Tags: windows, cmd

Есть файл index.html. Нужно через командную строку заменить подстроку `lang="ru"` на `lang="en"`. Как это можно сделать? Нужно именно через cmd, а не PowerShell и т.п.

Comment: Читай построчно, ищи заданную подстроку, если нашёл, заменяй, и пиши в новый файл. Вроде всё просто и плоско..

Comment: Тут принято отмечать ответы, которые помогли.

Answer (score 0):

Можно заменить только строку целиком.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
copy /y index.html b.txt
del /q index.html
for /f "delims=" %%a in (b.txt) do (
set asdfg=%%a
if %%a==lang="ru" set asdfg=lang="en"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !asdfg!>> index.html
endlocal
)
del /q b.txt
```

Если там какая-то постоянная строка вроде "<html lang="ru">", то нужно её целиком и менять.